# Riesz representation theorem application

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, riesz-representation-theorem

I need help with the second question below

[image]

My thoughts: Taking the first functional, by the riesz representation theorem, I can find a signed measure $v$ on $B[0,1]$ such that $l_1(p)=$ the integral of $c_0$ w.r.t $v$ between $0$ and $1$. But I don't know what to do next.

Thanks

Comment: A hint: If $p$ is a polynomial, think about $p(0)$ and $p(1)$.

Comment: Can you do one of them, and then I try and do the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along the lines of Nate's hint: consider the [Dirac Measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure) 
$$\delta_x(A) = 1_A(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & x \in A\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
First, do so with $x = 0$, then with $x = 1$.

---

For (i): we define the measure 
$$\delta_0(A) = 1_A(0) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & 0 \in A\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
We find that for polynomials $p(x) \in P$: 
$$\int_{[0,1]} p(x)\,d\delta_0 = p(0) = c_0 = l_1(p)$$ 
as desired.  We may extend this functional to other continuous functions by applying the same integral.  That is, for $f \in E$, we define 
$$l_1(f) = \int_{[0,1]}f(x)\,d\delta_0 = f(0)$$

Comment: Can you do one of them, and then I try and do the rest?

Comment: Updated. Does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks, but how do you know the integral is p(0)?

Comment: Write $$\int_{[0,1]} p(x)\,d\delta_0 =\int_{\{0\}} p(x)\,d\delta_0 + \int_{(0,1]} p(x)\,d\delta_0$$ does that clear things up?

Comment: Alternatively, it is sufficient to state $p(x) = c_0$ almost everywhere (with respect to this measure), from which it follows that $\int_{[0,1]}p(x)\, d\delta_0 = c_0 \delta_0([0,1])$

Comment: And for the second question, I use the measure [tex]\delta_1(A)[\tex]. Thanks, is there a way for me to 'boost' your reputation? What are the math tags I need to use on here?

Comment: Use dollar signs for the math tags.  For example, `$\int_{[0,1]} p(x)\, d \delta_1(A)$` renders as $\int_{[0,1]} p(x)\, d \delta_1(A)$ to give you in-line mathematics, whereas `$$\int_{[0,1]} p(x)\, d \delta_1(A)$$` renders as $$\int_{[0,1]} p(x)\, d \delta_1(A)$$ to give you "display" mathematics. Also, you can right-click any rendered mathematics and go to "show math as" to see how it was typeset. If you like my answer, you can press the up-arrow next to my question, and if you feel that I've answered my question completely, you can click the check-mark underneath to "accept" my answer.